# Pandas - df.compare() how to change self/other labels?

Tags: python, pandas

Using [df.compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) in Pandas, is it possible to change the labels of self/other from the output?

I need to send this output directly to less technically savvy users and would like to change them to more descriptive labels.

My code:

```
  if df_1.equals(df_2):
    return None
  else:
    return df_1.compare(df_2, align_axis=0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `rename` the index level to something more obvious:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,5,4], [5,2,3,1]])

df1.compare(df2, align_axis=0).rename(index={'self': 'left', 'other': 'right'}, level=-1)

           0    2    3
0 left   NaN  3.0  NaN
  right  NaN  5.0  NaN
1 left   1.0  NaN  4.0
  right  5.0  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: with align_axis=1 it's not updating the label with pandas libarary 1.1.0. Not sure what's wrong with the axis.

Comment: @ArpanSaini the rename specifies `index` which makes sense for `align_axis=0`, You would need to change that to `columns=` if you compare along axis=1

Comment: It worked perfectly fine with columns and align_axis=1 exactly for side by side comparison, Thank you so much @ALollz