# df.compare() how to change self/other labels with align_axis=1?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have two dataframes, then since pandas 1.1.0 I can compare them along axis 1 as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]], index=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,5,4], [5,2,3,1]], index=['A', 'B'])

df1.compare(df2, align_axis=1)
```

[image]

I would like to rename the self/other labels to something more descriptive.

I am aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909211/50065) for the `align_axis=0` case:

```
df1.compare(df2, align_axis=0).rename(index={'self': 'left', 'other': 'right'}, level=-1)
```

[image]

But that doesn't work for `align_axis=1`:

```
df1.compare(df2, align_axis=1).rename(index={'self': 'left', 'other': 'right'}, level=-1)
```

[image]

(I also tried with `level=0`).

I am also aware of [this open pull request](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/44365) that would add a `suffixes` argument to `pd.compare` that would allow you to do:

```
df1.compare(df2, align_axis=1, suffixes=["left", "right"])
```

but until that pull request gets merged, what is the way to currently do this in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When is axis 1 you should change `index` to `columns` in `rename`

```
df1.compare(df2, align_axis=1).rename(columns={'self': 'left', 'other': 'right'}, level=-1)
Out[56]: 
     0          2          3      
  left right left right left right
A  NaN   NaN  3.0   5.0  NaN   NaN
B  1.0   5.0  NaN   NaN  4.0   1.0
```